# Holomorphic function with given real part on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

From de Branges' book Hilbert spaces of Entire Functions (page 2):

If $h(\theta)$ is a continuous real-valued $2\pi$-periodic function, define $$g(z) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i \theta} + z}{e^{i\theta} - z} h(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta, \; \; |z| < 1.$$ Then $\lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \mathrm{Re} \, g(re^{i \theta}) = h(\theta).$

Is this a well-known integral? It is implied that it is but I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the real part of $g$ is just the Poisson integral of $h,$ which solves the Dirichlet problem in the disc with boundary function $h.$